# BaseFare equal to BT in GetReservationRS

Tags: sabre

Im trying to retrieve some tickets details but the problem is

BaseFare, Some tickets i found **BaseFare** equal to **BT**

Some ticket i get float value so the question

**how to get the basefare for the ticket when i retrieve it as BT**

Comment: Where are you getting the fare, from the price quote?

Comment: First of all the BT indicates that you have a negotiated fare, but it should be followed by the amount. would you mind to share your response. Don't forget to blur the sensitive data(ticket number or any other pax info), before to share the response.

Comment: @AndyK im getting the price from GetReservationRS request am i wrong ?

Comment: There are multiple fields returned with GetReservationRS. Without seeing the full response it will be difficult to answer your question.